# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SQL array must not be empty

Tags: java, oracle, spring-jdbc, batch-updates

I have below DBImporter class which is working fine and also inserting data correctly in database table. I am trying to fetch data from .CSV file and inserting into Oracle table.

Till now i was processing only one file in my directory and which is working fine. Now i want to process more than one file. So during run the first file process correctly and inserted data, in second file it started reading data and throw an error as :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SQL array must not be empty
```

Below is my DBimporter class. I think the error is during final commit batch somewhere in line here but not sure

jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sqlBatch.toArray(new String[sqlBatch.size()]));

```
@Service
public class DBImporter {

    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DBImporter.class);
    private static final List<String> NULL_VALUES = Arrays.asList("", "N.A", "N.A", "UNKNOWN");
    private static final List<String> COL_HEADERS = Arrays.asList("ID", "NM", "TYE", "SA");
    private static final int BATCH_SIZE = 50;

    private boolean eof = false;
    private String tableName;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void setTableName(String tableName) {
        this.tableName = tableName;
    }

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = IOException.class)
    public void processFile(BufferedReader reader, String tableName) {
        this.tableName = tableName;
        List<String> sqlBatch = new ArrayList<String>(BATCH_SIZE);

        log.info("Starte auslesen der Daten");
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        log.info("Start time: " + t1);

        jdbcTemplate.execute("DELETE FROM " + tableName);

        while (!eof) {
            try {
                Map<String, ColumnData> dbColumns = getDBColumns();

                // Get a list of db column data related to the column headers.
                List<ColumnData> columnData = COL_HEADERS.stream().map(dbColumns::get).collect(toList());

                // Get the next valid data row if its starts from "FRO" or "BO".
                List<String> dataRow = findNextLineStartingWith(reader, "R", "T");

                String query = createSql(columnData, dataRow);
                sqlBatch.add(query);

                // Process batch.
                if (sqlBatch.size() >= BATCH_SIZE) {
                    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sqlBatch.toArray(new String[sqlBatch.size()]));
                    sqlBatch.clear();
                }
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                break;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }

        // Commit the final batch.
        jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sqlBatch.toArray(new String[sqlBatch.size()]));
        sqlBatch.clear();

        long delta = System.currentTimeMillis() - t1;
        log.info("Total runtime : " + delta / 1000 + " seconds");
    }

    /**
     * Create a SQL insert query using the data row.
     * 
     * @param tableName  Name of the table.
     * @param columnData Column data list.
     * @param dataRow    Data row to be inserted.
     * @return Generated SQL query string.
     */
    private String createSql(List<ColumnData> columnData, List<String> dataRow) {
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>(columnData.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < columnData.size(); i++) {
            if (NULL_VALUES.contains(dataRow.get(i))) {
                values.add("NULL");
            } else if (columnData.get(i).getType() >= Types.NUMERIC && columnData.get(i).getType() <= Types.DOUBLE) {
                values.add(dataRow.get(i));
            } else {
                values.add("'" + dataRow.get(i).replace("'", "''") + "'");
            }
        }

        return "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (" +
        columnData.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).map(ColumnData::getName).collect(joining(", ")) +
        ", SYSTEM_INSERTED_AT) VALUES (" +
        values.stream().collect(joining(", ")) +
        ", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
    }

    /**
     * Find the next line starting with the given string and split it into columns.
     * 
     * @param reader   BufferedReader object to be used.
     * @param prefixes A list of prefixes to look for in the string.
     * @return List of data objects.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private List<String> findNextLineStartingWith(BufferedReader reader, String... prefixes) throws IOException {
        while (true) {
            String line = readLineOrThrow(reader);
            for (String prefix : prefixes)
                if (line.startsWith(prefix)) {
                    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
                    // Split the line using the delimiter.
                    data.addAll(Arrays.asList(line.split(";")));

                    // Build the row to be inserted.
                    List<String> row = Arrays.asList(data.get(1), data.get(2).trim(), "", "");                      

                    return row;
                }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Read a single line in the file.
     * 
     * @param reader BufferedReader object to be used.
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private String readLineOrThrow(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            this.eof = true;
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected EOF");
        }

        return line.trim();
    }

    /**
     * Read database column metadata.
     * 
     * @param tableName Name of the table to process.
     * @return A map containing column information.
     */
    private Map<String, ColumnData> getDBColumns() {
        Map<String, ColumnData> result = new HashMap<>();
        try (Connection connection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection()) {
            ResultSet rs = connection.getMetaData().getColumns(null, null, tableName, null);
            while (rs.next()) {
                String columnName = rs.getString(4).toUpperCase();
                int type = rs.getInt(5);
                result.put(columnName, new ColumnData(columnName, type));
            }
            return result;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below changes:

```
        // Commit the final batch.
if (sqlBatch.size() > 0){
   jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sqlBatch.toArray(new String[sqlBatch.size()]));
   sqlBatch.clear();
}
```

And

```
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = IOException.class)
    public void processFile(BufferedReader reader, String tableName) {
        eof = false;
        ...
```

But if you want a more clear and safe solution do changes in your code as below:

```
public class DBImporter {

    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DBImporter.class);
    private static final List<String> NULL_VALUES = Arrays.asList("", "N.A", "N.A", "UNKNOWN");
    private static final List<String> COL_HEADERS = Arrays.asList("USER_ID", "NAME", "TYPE", "SRC_DATA");
    private static final int BATCH_SIZE = 50;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = IOException.class)
    public void processFile(BufferedReader reader, String tableName) {
        AtomicBoolean eof = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        List<String> sqlBatch = new ArrayList<String>(BATCH_SIZE);

        log.info("Starte auslesen der Daten");
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        log.info("Start time: " + t1);

        jdbcTemplate.execute("DELETE FROM " + tableName);

        while (!eof.get()) {
            try {
                Map<String, ColumnData> dbColumns = getDBColumns(tableName);

                // Get a list of db column data related to the column headers.
                List<ColumnData> columnData = COL_HEADERS.stream().map(dbColumns::get).collect(toList());

                // Get the next valid data row if its starts from "R" or "T".
                List<String> dataRow = findNextLineStartingWith(reader, eof, "R", "T");

                String query = createSql(tableName, columnData, dataRow);
                sqlBatch.add(query);

                // Process batch.
                if (sqlBatch.size() >= BATCH_SIZE) {
                    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sqlBatch.toArray(new String[sqlBatch.size()]));
                    sqlBatch.clear();
                }
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                break;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }

        // Commit the final batch.
        jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sqlBatch.toArray(new String[sqlBatch.size()]));
        sqlBatch.clear();

        long delta = System.currentTimeMillis() - t1;
        log.info("Total runtime : " + delta / 1000 + " seconds");
    }

    /**
     * Create a SQL insert query using the data row.
     *
     * @param tableName  Name of the table.
     * @param columnData Column data list.
     * @param dataRow    Data row to be inserted.
     * @return Generated SQL query string.
     */
    private String createSql(String tableName, List<ColumnData> columnData, List<String> dataRow) {
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>(columnData.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < columnData.size(); i++) {
            if (NULL_VALUES.contains(dataRow.get(i))) {
                values.add("NULL");
            } else if (columnData.get(i).getType() >= Types.NUMERIC && columnData.get(i).getType() <= Types.DOUBLE) {
                values.add(dataRow.get(i));
            } else {
                values.add("'" + dataRow.get(i).replace("'", "''") + "'");
            }
        }

        return "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (" +
                columnData.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).map(ColumnData::getName).collect(joining(", ")) +
                ", SYSTEM_INSERTED_AT) VALUES (" +
                values.stream().collect(joining(", ")) +
                ", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
    }

    /**
     * Find the next line starting with the given string and split it into columns.
     *
     * @param reader   BufferedReader object to be used.
     * @param prefixes A list of prefixes to look for in the string.
     * @return List of data objects.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private List<String> findNextLineStartingWith(BufferedReader reader, AtomicBoolean eof, String... prefixes) throws IOException {
        while (true) {
            String line = readLineOrThrow(reader, eof);
            for (String prefix : prefixes)
                if (line.startsWith(prefix)) {
                    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
                    // Split the line using the delimiter.
                    data.addAll(Arrays.asList(line.split(";")));

                    // Build the row to be inserted.
                    List<String> row = Arrays.asList(data.get(1), data.get(2).trim(), "", "");

                    // Insert type depending on the prefix.
                    if (prefix.equals("R"))
                        row.set(2, "USER");
                    else if (prefix.equals("T"))
                        row.set(2, "PERM");

                    row.set(3, String.join(";", row.subList(0, 3)));

                    return row;
                }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Read a single line in the file.
     *
     * @param reader BufferedReader object to be used.
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private String readLineOrThrow(BufferedReader reader, AtomicBoolean eof) throws IOException {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            eof.set(true);
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected EOF");
        }

        return line.trim();
    }

    /**
     * Read database column metadata.
     *
     * @param tableName Name of the table to process.
     * @return A map containing column information.
     */
    private Map<String, ColumnData> getDBColumns(String tableName) {
        Map<String, ColumnData> result = new HashMap<>();
        try (Connection connection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection()) {
            ResultSet rs = connection.getMetaData().getColumns(null, null, tableName, null);
            while (rs.next()) {
                String columnName = rs.getString(4).toUpperCase();
                int type = rs.getInt(5);
                result.put(columnName, new ColumnData(columnName, type));
            }
            return result;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the error is gone but the problem is its processing the first file correctly and inserting but during the second file its not inserting anything

Comment: Try to move `private boolean eof = false;` inside your method `processFile ` and pass it as a argument to other mothods where you need.

Comment: @Vasif: Good point. If the `eof` is not reset between the passing of differents files it wont work.

Comment: can you please update in answer where i should pass this exactly.. i tried to remove the private boolean eof = false and trying to move in processFile but getting an error

Comment: or you can simply on 1st line of your `processFile` reset it's value as `eof = false;`. Just be sure this is not right way of doing it. You Service should be thread safe and shouldn't contain any state

Answer (score 1):

There is the possibility that your final batch is empty.

This is possible in case you just commited `BATCH_SIZE` entries and have cleared the `sqlBatch`. In case your `while` loop exits at this point of time,
there are no elements to commit.

You'll want to fix that by adding a size check, for example:

```
// Commit the final batch (only if there is something left)
if (sqlBatch.isEmpty() == false) {
    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sqlBatch.toArray(new String[sqlBatch.size()]));
    sqlBatch.clear();
}
```

---

**Edit:**

As `@Vasif` pointed out you'll need to reset the `eof` between different calls of the method.

A simple solution (albeit somewhat `hacky`) would be

```
boolean eof = false
while (!eof) {
    try {

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        eof = true;
        break;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

A proper solution would be to refactor your code so that it does not rely on these exception being thrown.

Some tips:

- Get rid of `readLineOrThrow`.
- Remove the `while(true)` in `findNextLineStartingWith` and instead return an empty list if the next line is `null`.
- Adjust the outside loop to handle this return value appropriately.
- (Note: you might also need to break the loop if you get an `IOException`).

Comment: you mean i need to change the batch_size which is 50 now ?

Comment: can you please tell exactly where i need to make change..i am quiet new and tried this jdbc batchupdate

Comment: now the error is gone but the problem is its processing the first file correctly and inserting but during the second file its not inserting anything

Comment: i have updated my question and also mentione class file which is passsing file to DBImporter class

Comment: I've updated the answer once more. I am not going to write the `proper` code for you, but I left you some tips on what to change.

Comment: its working now thanks just boolean eof = false this line we need to add in processfile at top

Comment: @Andrew: Consider doing a proper solution anyway, especially if that is not a private project.